# How to create a unit test for a simple I/O subroutine in Perl

Tags: perl, unit-testing, io, compiler-errors, package

ErrorLibrary.pm :

```
package Artopi::Builder::ErrorLibrary;

use strict;
use warnings;    

use constant {
    # wiki link included as a variable in this example
    CABLING_ERROR => {
    errorCode => 561,
    message => "cabling is not correct\n\n ",
    t => { template => 'disabled'},
    page =>'http://w.error-sol.com/index/Builder/ErrorCodes/_CABLING_ERROR',
    },
};
```

Here is the error_post method that I'm trying to test. I am trying to unit test so that the expected it output is correct. My current test won't compile properly, I can't see what is majorly wrong with my code. It's probably something I should be able to see/know.

ErrorPost.pm :

```
package Artopi::Builder::ErrorPost;

use strict;
use warnings;
use Artopi::Builder::ErrorLibrary;


# takes error name as a param and prints out the message contained in the error hash.
sub error_post {

    my($error) = @_;
    print ($error->{ message });  

}
1;
```

Below is the current test that I have come up with. But it gives me an error saying : *'Can't use string Artopi::Builder::ErrorPost as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use at /ErrorPost.pm Line 12*

```
error_post.t :
    my $error = Artopi::Builder::ErrorLibrary->CABLING_ERROR; 
    # expected values
    my $exp_output = ($error->{message});
    my $exp_input =  Artopi::Builder::ErrorLibrary->CABLING_ERROR;

    # input value as a parameter of error_post method
    my $error_in = Artropi::Builder::ErrorPost->error_post($exp_input);

    # checking that exp_input matches the expected output after the output has
    # been passed through the error_post method
    is($error_in, qr/$exp_output/, 'This is the correct output');
```

Any suggestions? :)

Comment: 1) Since `error_post` has no `return` statement, it will return the value of the last statement, which is `print`. `print` returns 1 on success, so `$error_in` will generally be 1. 2) `is()` checks that the first argument is equal to the second argument. You're checking if 1 is equal to a compiled regex, which is not the same as checking that it matches a regex. [`like()`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::More#like) allows you to match against a regex, but I think you want to test equality here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Test::Output](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::Output) to test printed stuff.

```
use Test::More;
use Test::Output;

sub error_post {
    my ($error) = @_;
    print( $error->{message} );
}

stdout_is { error_post( { message => 'foo' } ) } "foo", 
  'the error message is correct';

# equivalent without the bare block/map-ish syntax
stdout_is(
    sub { error_post( { message => 'foo' } ) },
    "foo",
    'the error message is correct'
);

# and using like
stdout_like { error_post($error) } qr/foo/,
  'the error message looks correct';

done_testing;
```

In this case, the return value of your sub is not tested at all. If you want both, you would have to save it in your anonymous sub and test it later.

```
my $rv;
stdout_is { $rv = error_post( { message => 'foo' } ) } "foo", 
  'the error message is correct';
is $rv, 'expected', '... and the return value is too';
```

Test::Output uses [Capture::Tiny](http://p3rl.org/Capture::Tiny) under the hood, which is great if you just need to make output in code you do not control *go away*.

Comment: And for integration tests with printed output, I suggest getting a QA intern. :)